# Need code optimization but can't figure out how to do that

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization, game-development

I have developed hole game, where player must absorb some cubes on the floor everything seems fine, just there is some optimization problem. I think problem is caused by looking for absorbable object which are in range to fell in the hole, I have 2 method and they are called in FixedUpdate. In method called CountNearbyCubes on every frame I am iterating on over the Cubes list, sometimes it's count is even 500-600 objects and if some of the objects are near the hole, then they are added into another list and this second list is used in method named AttractCubes. In this method I am iterating all over the objects and looking their transform position and pushing them toward hole's transform position.

Here is both method and FixedUpdate's code also I am adding game's screenshot for more clearity.

sorry if my question is confusing. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
 void FixedUpdate() {

    //count real nearbyCubes
    CountNearbyCubes(ref NearbyCubes, CubesContainers, GravityCenterTransform.position);
    //count minor nearbyCubes
    AttractCubes(NearbyCubes);


}

private void AttractCubes(List<GameObject> cubes) {
    foreach (GameObject cube in cubes) {

        if (!cube.GetComponent<AbsorbableObject>().IsAbsorbed) {

            Vector3 force = CentripetalMovement.GetGravitationForce(GravityCenterTransform, cube.transform, Mass, CubeMass);

            if (cube.tag == "Bomb") {
                force /= 5;
            }

            cube.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(force, ForceMode.Impulse);

        }

    }

}


private void CountNearbyCubes(ref List<GameObject> nearbyCubes, GameObject cubesContainer, Vector3 gravityCenter) {
    foreach (Transform cube in cubesContainer.transform) {

        if (Vector3.SqrMagnitude(cube.position - gravityCenter) < Mathf.Pow(NearbyDistance, 2)) {
            if (!nearbyCubes.Contains(cube.gameObject)) {
                if (cube.tag == "Cube" && !cube.gameObject.GetComponent<CubeController>().IsAbsorbed)
                    nearbyCubes.Add(cube.gameObject);
                else if (cube.tag == "Bomb")
                    nearbyCubes.Add(cube.gameObject);
            }
        }
        else {
            nearbyCubes.Remove(cube.gameObject);
        }

    }

}
```

[image]

If you understand what I am doing, just wonder if there is another way which will be more efficient to increase fps in runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the physics engine!

I can think of two ways to go about it:

1. Attach a collider to the hole game object, mark it as a trigger, and
   catch all collisions on `Collider.OnTriggerEnter(Collider)`.
2. Use [SphereCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) directly.

Comment: This alternatives look much more efficient, thanks for your response, I'll use one of them to replace current system

Comment: @Chestera I remembered there's also [Physics.SphereCastNonAlloc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCastNonAlloc.html) which is even more efficient.